# 'fileSystemModule' was not found in '@nativescript/core'

Tags: nativescript

Trying to write to a local file in Android.

Tried import {fileSystemModule} from "@nativescript/core"; but get error 'fileSystemModule' was not found in '@nativescript/core'.

Have also tried import {fileSystemModule} from "@nativescript/core/file-system" but it doesn't exist. I'm using plain Javascript.

Nativescript 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import paths are updated in the recent versions of NativeScript. You can access these directly now without having to go through `fileSystemModule`. See code below:

```js
import { knownFolders, File, Folder } from '@nativescript/core';
```

To write to a local file using the latest NativeScript would look like this:

```js
writeToFile(): void {
  const folder = knownFolders.documents().getFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
  const file = folder.getFile(FILE_NAME.txt);
  file.writeText(SOME_STRING_TO_WRITE_TO_FILE);
}
```

To write to an accessible location in Android, you can use the following:

```js
writeToFile(): void {
    const folderPath = path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString())
    const folder = Folder.fromPath(folderPath);
    const file = folder.getFile(FILE_NAME.txt);
    file.writeText(SOME_STRING_TO_WRITE_TO_FILE);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Using the code above, I'm getting an obscure path that I cannot find. /data/user/0/org.nativescript.datacapture/files/datacapture/data.txt. How do I write straight to the Documents folder then my subfolder.

Comment: Sorry further to my previous comment we can only use internal storage for the App as we cannot guarantee external storage being available. We are using Samsung Galaxy Tab A, but am struggling to write the data to a sensible accessible location.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. It looks like your code is writing to External Storage. We can only use Internal Storage for our App. We cannot guarantee that an SD card will be installed.

Comment: You should be able to replace `getExternalStorageDirectory` with `getDataDirectory`, `getRootDirectory`  or `getDownloadCacheDirectory` to use other directories. Not sure if any of those works with your use case